# How can I copy the nullability state of a source Spark Dataframe schema and force it onto a target Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm using Databricks. Let's say I have two Spark Dataframes (I'm using PySpark):

- df_source
- df_target

If df_source has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
```

And df_target has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = false)
```

How do I efficiently create another Dataframe, df_final where the (nullable = true/false) property from the df_source can be forced onto df_target?

I have tried doing the following:

```
df_final = spark.createDataFrame(df_target.rdd, schema = df_source.schema)
```

By this method, I'm able to achieve the desired result but it seems to be taking a long amount of time for the dataset size that I have. For smaller datasets, it works fine. Using the collect() function instead of an rdd conversion is obviously way worse for larger datasets.

I would like to point out that the only thing I want to do here is copy the nullability part from the source schema and change it accordingly in target, for the final dataframe.

Is there a way to do some sort of nullability casting, which works similar to .withColumn() performance wise, without RDD conversion, without explicit column name specification in the code? The column ordering is already aligned between source and target.

**Additional context**: The reason I need to do this is because I need to write (append) df_final to a Google BigQuery table using the Spark BQ connector. So, even if my Spark Dataframe doesn't have any null values in a column but the nullability property is set to true, the BigQuery table will reject the write operation since that column in the BigQuery table may have the nullable property set to false, and the schema mismatches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know for a fact that `age` can't be null, you can `coalesce` age and a constant literal to create a non-nullable field. For fields where the `nullable` field has to be convered from `false` to `true`, `when` expression can be used.

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, LongType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_source_schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), False),
    StructField("id", LongType(), False),
    StructField("age", LongType(), True),
])

df_target_schema = StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("id", LongType(), False),
    StructField("age", LongType(), False),
])

df_source = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1, 18, ), ], df_source_schema)
df_source.printSchema()
"""
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
"""

df_target = spark.createDataFrame([("a", 1, 18), ], df_target_schema)
df_target.printSchema()
"""
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = false)
"""

# Construct selection expression based on the logic described above

target_field_nullable_map = {field.name: field.nullable for field in df_target.schema}

selection_expr = []

for src_field in df_source.schema:
    field_name = src_field.name
    field_type = src_field.dataType
    
    if target_field_nullable_map[field_name] != src_field.nullable:
        if src_field.nullable:
            selection_expr.append(F.when(F.col(field_name).isNotNull(), F.col(field_name)).otherwise(F.lit(None)).alias(field_name))
        else:
            selection_expr.append(F.coalesce(F.col(field_name), F.lit("-1").cast(field_type)).alias(field_name))
    else:
        selection_expr.append(F.col(field_name))

df_final = df_target.select(*selection_expr)
df_final.printSchema()
"""
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
"""
```

### Why does this work?

For a `coalesce` expression to be `null` all it's child expression have to be null as seen from [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4624e59ac606868f3f370d84bc2dd49ced2e4aae/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/nullExpressions.scala#L53).
Since `lit` is a non-null expression when [`value != null`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4624e59ac606868f3f370d84bc2dd49ced2e4aae/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/literals.scala#L333) `coalesce` results in a non-nullable column.

A `when` expression is nullable is any branch is nullable of if the else expression is nullable as noted [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/conditionalExpressions.scala#L156).

Comment: This only works with explicit column naming. The age, name, id situation described in the question is just a simplified use case. Would there be a solution to do this without having to manually look at each column, using a source dataframe?

Comment: @UttkarshDutt you can iterate over the columns and apply the logic per column, I have edited the answer to include the logic for doing this.

Comment: apologies for the delay. This perfectly solves my problem without the ,rdd conversion.